# using tabbed panel in struts 2

Tags: java, jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery

my requirement is to make two tabs in a jsp page using struts 2,so that when i call the action from tab1 the tab 1 will load and when i call the action from the tab2 the tab2 will load and display the updated data.How can i do this?also whenever i call an action from the tab2 then how the tab2 will load automatically.?

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
  <html>  
      <head>
      <s:head theme="ajax" debug="true"/>
      </head>

      <body>

      <s:tabbedPanel id="test" >

      <s:div id="one" label="Tab 1" theme="ajax">
          <form action="tab1action">
          </form>
      </s:div>

      <s:div id="two" label="Tab 2" theme="ajax" >
       <s:form   href="tab2action">
           second Tab 
       </s:form>
      </s:div>
     </s:tabbedPanel>
      </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use `useSelectedTabCookie="true"`in tabbedpanel tag

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

 <%@ taglib prefix="sd" uri="/struts-dojo-tags"%>

 <html>
 <head>
 <sd:head/>
 </head>
 <body>
    <sd:tabbedpanel id="test" useSelectedTabCookie="true">

  <sd:div id="one" label="Tab 1" theme="ajax" >
      <s:form action="tab1action">
       <s:submit />
      </form>
  </sd:div>

  <sd:div id="two" label="Tab 2" theme="ajax" >
   <s:form   action="tab2action">
       <s:submit />
   </s:form>
  </sd:div>
 </sd:tabbedpanel>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: suppose i call an action from tab2 page in which there is an updation of record then how after processing how the tab2 will load.?because the same page is forward after the success and it will load the first tab

Comment: I added in the answer. you just need is to add `useSelectedTabCookie="true"` in tabbed panel tag.. try code snipped in the answer it will show you example